# Mac M1 openssl CLion compile problems

Tags: c, macos, openssl, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I have the following task: Write a C/C++ program that creates dh parameters.

I use CLion. OpenSSL was originally installed and I can use all OpenSSL commands in the terminal.

```
MacBook-Air-Nikita ~ % openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
```

But, in CLion, I can't add any libraries, because it doesn't see it. I install new OpenSSL using Brew successfully; it has this path:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i/
```

But CLion doesn't see any libraries. So I add to project CMakeList.txt these lines:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i/include/)
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i/ )
set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
```

After that, I can include all libraries that I want, but it's not working. When I try to run program with any function from the libraries, the builder fails.

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>

int main(){
    RAND_bytes(10, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_RAND_bytes", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [PV181_HW03] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PV181_HW03.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PV181_HW03.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [PV181_HW03] Error 2
```

Can anybody advise me how to fix this?